# Azure Container Instance run FTP ports not open

Tags: azure, docker, ftp, azure-container-instances

I want to run ftp server to azure container instance. I am using instruction https://hub.docker.com/r/stilliard/pure-ftpd/. Everything works fine locally. My command for run locally  `docker run -e FTP_USER_NAME=testapp -e FTP_USER_PASS=12345 -e FTP_USER_HOME=/home/testapp -e "PUBLICHOST=localhost" -e FTP_PASSIVE_PORTS=20000:20008 -p 21:21 -p 20000-20008:20000-20008 stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened` But when I start an Azure Container Instance the connection does not work for me. My command `az container create -g test-dev --name test-dev-aci --image stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened --cpu 1 --memory 2 --ports 20000 20001 20002 20003 20004 20005 20006 20007 20008 21  --environment-variables FTP_USER_NAME=testapp FTP_USER_PASS=12345 FTP_USER_HOME=/home/testapp PUBLICHOST=test-ftp.westeurope.azurecontainer.io FTP_PASSIVE_PORTS=20000:20008 --ip-address public --dns-name-label test-ftp`. I checked command telnet. For local case all ports are open but for Azure Container Instance only port 21 is open ports 20000-20008 are closed (maybe there are port limits.). Could you please help to run ftp in azure container instance? I will be glad to other solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 5 ports per IP by default on ACI. Also it is better to use SFTP on port 22, you wouldn't need to open so many ports.

Comment: thanks, this is the answer to my question )